# Is it correct to conclude about the values of limits using comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have two infinite sums $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i$ such that $0 \le a_i \le b_i, \forall i$ ($a_i,b_i$ are real). And the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_i$ converges, ie. $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}b_i = L$ for some finite $L$. 
Then by using [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) I can say that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$ also converges. Let it converge to a value $M$.
Then would it be correct to say $M \le L$ ?

I can see that from the partial sums
$$
A_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i \\
B_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}b_i \\
A_n \le B_n, \forall n
$$

and thus $M \le L$ should hold. Is this reasoning valid ? It might be a trivial question but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Your reasoning  is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can say that. At the end of the day, infinite sums are just limits of partial sums. And we have that for limits $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = b$, if $a_n < b_n$, then $a <b$.

Comment: Use \ before $lim \rightarrow \lim$ to make it look better.